# How do I create a keystore for a SP from the IdP metadata

Tags: java, spring-mvc, saml

I am working to set up my SP with an IdP. They gave me the link to their metadata. I was able to get the SAML Sample application working. I switched the sample metadata with my IdP's metadata, but it seems I'm having a problem with the signing certificate.

I've tried creating my own keystore and importing the x509 certificate data from the IdP's metadata file, but I am getting an error that I have the wrong signature.
I've also tried to create a keystore from the certificate file directly, but I get an error that I am lacking a Private Key.

I wasn't given a any keys or certificate files directly from the IdP, they told me that all of the data I needed was in the Metadata file.

Here is my keyManager bean in my context.xml file:

```
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="file:F:/Certificates/PESTestKeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="changeit"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="dagtestkeystore" value="changeit"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="dagtestkeystore"/>
    </bean>
```

My Metadata generator I know that it requires the sha256. Originally I didn't specify and was getting an error that I was using sha1, but the IdP was expecting sha256:

```
    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                <property name="entityId" value="urn:test:dag:dagtest"/>
                <property name="extendedMetadata">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <property name="signMetadata" value="true"/>
                        <property name="signingKey" value="dagtestkeystore"/>
                        <property name="signingAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
Saml 

Relying Party: 
urn:test:dag:dagtest 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: MSIS0038: SAML Message has wrong signature. Issuer: 'urn:test:dag:dagtest'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.Contract.SamlContractUtility.CreateSamlMessage(MSISSamlBindingMessage message)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the SAML AuthnRequest is performed with the private key of your SP. The public key included in the certificate provided with the SAML IdP meta data is only needed to verify the signature of the Assertion / SAML Response sent by the IdP.

Comment: So can you elaborate more on the error message I'm getting. It has something to do with the signature, correct? How can I have the wrong signature?

Comment: First of all you need to trace the SAML AuthnRequest. Potentially your SP is using a signature algorithm that the IdP does not accept .... this is especially true for Microsoft based IdPs like ADFS or Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: "This is the error message I am getting:"

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.XmlSignature.SignatureVerificationFailedException: MSIS0038: SAML Message has wrong signature. Issuer: 'urn:test:dag:dagtest'.
```

**Resolution**:
**Case 1**: AuthnRequest is NOT necessarily signed.

**Resolution to Case 1**: In the SAML2 Update 1 Properties, you can uncheck Sign AuthnRequest. Please refer to [Cannot log in with SSO using SAML (Multi-SSO) & ADFS 2.0 (Error 364 & 303)](https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=b51ffa29db58dbc01dcaf3231f9619cf).

**Case 2**: AuthnRequest has to be signed.

In your case, your SP signs the AuthnRequest, but SAML IdP (i.e., Microsoft ADFS) fails to use your SP public certificate/key to verify the signature of AuthnRequest.

**Resolution to Case 2**: You need to provide the URL of your SAML SP metadata to your SAML IdP (i.e., Microsoft ADFS) so that 
Microsoft ADFS can download SAML SP metadata, extract SP public certificate/key from SP metadata, and then use SP public certificate/key to validate the signed AuthnRequest.

**Sub-question** "I am working to set up my SP with an IdP. They gave me the link to their metadata. I was able to get the SAML Sample application working. I switched the sample metadata with my IdP's metadata, but it seems I'm having a problem with the signing certificate."

**Answer**:
The SAML Sample application working, because they have uploaded SAML SP metadata file of SAML Sample application into their SAML IdP.

Two typical approaches for configuring SAML SP with SAML IdP, depending on different requirements of SAML IdP are listed below.

(1) You need to create SAML SP private key and public certificate/key for your own SP application, generate your SAML SP metadata file (which only includes public certificate/key), then you have two options

(Option I) upload the SP metatdata file to the SAML IdP.

(Option II) provide the URL of the SP metatdata file, then SAML IdP (such as Microsoft ADFS) can download the SP metatdata file from the URL.

(2) Some SAML IdPs require administrators manually upload the SAML SP public certificate/key, and submit entityID and AssertionConsumerService URL of SAML SP.

**Question**: "I've tried creating my own keystore and importing the x509 certificate data from the IdP's metadata file, but I am getting an error that I have the wrong signature."

**Answer**:
(1) Usually SAML SP needs to create different key and certificate which are separate from SAML IdP. In other words, the public certificate/key carried by SAML SP and SAML IdP should be different, as shown by the sample SAML SP metatdata "sp-example-org.xml" and the sample SAML IdP "idp-metadata.xml" provided by [Shibboleth IdP and SP testbed](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP/tree/master/shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/metadata) at GitHub repository.

[How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository provides the instruction on building a SAML IdP and SAML SP using Shibboleth SAML IdP, OpenLDAP and Shibboleth SAML SP.

(I) shibboleth-sp-testapp/shibboleth-sp/
provides the example of SAML SP key and certificate generated by OpenSSL.

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=sp.example.org" -keyout /etc/ssl/private/sp.example.org.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/sp.example.org.crt
```

(II) shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/credentials/
provides the example of SAML IdP keys and certificates.

(III) shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/metadata/
provides the example of the corresponding SAML IdP metadata file and SAML SP metadata file.

**Question**: "I've also tried to create a keystore from the certificate file directly, but I get an error that I am lacking a Private Key."

**Answer**:
IdP's metadata file only includes the public certificate/key, but does **NOT** include the private key.

Therefore, you can **NOT** create your own keystore by importing the x509 certificate data from the IdP's metadata file.

**Question**: "I wasn't given a any keys or certificate files directly from the IdP, they told me that all of the data I needed was in the Metadata file."

**Answer**:
They are correct. All of the data you needed was in the IdP Metadata file.

IdP Metadata file only includes public certificates, NOT private keys.

You can manually extract the public certificate/key from the IdP metadata, and then create public certificate file using the template provided by
[shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/credentials/idp-signing.crt](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP/blob/master/shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/credentials/idp-signing.crt). Note that usually you do NOT need to create public certificate file of SAML IdP, because most of SAML SPs (such as Shibboleth SAML SP) will extract the public certificate from the IdP metadata file when required (as described by "Two typical approaches for configuring SAML SP with SAML IdP, depending on different requirements of SAML IdP" in the **Resolution** above).